# Spring Boot ActiveMQ - Port already in use: 1099

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic

I am new in ActiveMQ and I need to create spring boot aplication where are publis activeMQ queues. Therefore I created the simple SpringBoot application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class Application {

  @Bean 
  JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myJmsContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
      SimpleJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleJmsListenerContainerFactory();
      factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
      return factory;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(new File("activemq-data"));
      // Launch the application
      ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
      System.out.println(" ************************ Asyn queue start ************************ ");        
  }
}
```

Then I created a Listneres as well:

```
@Component
public class Receiver {

    @Autowired
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context;


    @JmsListener(destination = "mailbox-destination", containerFactory = "myJmsContainerFactory")
    public void receiveMessageFromMailbox(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received <" + message + "> mailbox");
        //context.close();
        FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(new File("activemq-data"));
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "testqueue-destination", containerFactory = "myJmsContainerFactory")
    public void receiveMessageFromTestQueue(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received <" + message + "> testqueue");
        //context.close();
        FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(new File("activemq-data"));
    }
}
```

After I start it, it looks ok.

For testing I created a simple test:

```
public class Testing {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
      try {
          // Create a ConnectionFactory
          ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");
          // Create a Connection
          Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
          connection.start();
          // Create a Session
          Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
          // Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
          Destination destination = session.createQueue("testqueue-destination");
          // Create a MessageProducer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
          MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
          producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
          // Create a messages
          String text = "Hello world! From: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : ";
          TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(text);
          // Tell the producer to send the message
          System.out.println("Sent message: "+ message.hashCode() + " : " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + message);
          producer.send(message);
          // Clean up
          session.close();
          connection.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Caught: " + e);
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
}
```

But when I run Testing.main then the error occur:

[main] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext - Failed to create local registry
java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1099; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:341)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:249)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:411)
    at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:208)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.setup(RegistryImpl.java:152)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.(RegistryImpl.java:112)
    at java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(LocateRegistry.java:239)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext.createConnector(ManagementContext.java:418)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext.findTigerMBeanServer(ManagementContext.java:363)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext.findMBeanServer(ManagementContext.java:330)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext.getMBeanServer(ManagementContext.java:172)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext.start(ManagementContext.java:80)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startManagementContext(BrokerService.java:2031)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:477)

I think the problem is in testing method. But I do not know what is incorrect. Is there someone who can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run `netstat` command to check whether the port is in use or not?

For linux `netstat -pnlt | grep 1099`

For windows `netstat -np TCP | find "1099"`

Answer (score 0):

I know the port is use by SpringBoot application. After the SpringBoot application is start then the following log is print:

```
[           main] o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : Using Persistence Adapter: MemoryPersistenceAdapter
[           main] o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : ActiveMQ 5.4.2 JMS Message Broker (localhost) is starting
[           main] o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org/
[  JMX connector] o.a.a.broker.jmx.ManagementContext       : JMX consoles can connect to service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
[           main] o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : ActiveMQ JMS Message Broker (localhost, ID:CZ408016-49987-1470397291692-0:1) started
[           main] o.a.activemq.broker.TransportConnector   : Connector vm://localhost Started
[           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
[           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483647
[           main] c.c.e.asynqueue.spring.Application       : Started Application in 3.117 seconds (JVM running for 4.52)
```

But I have assumed then I can connect to broker whit the following code:

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");
// Create a Connection
Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();
```